# Load Script in runtime and be sure when it's loaded

Tags: javascript

Inside a script file I have to dynamicaly import another script and use functions and variables defined inside of it.

Right now, I'm adding it to the `HEAD` section of the Page, but just after adding it, functions and variables defined inside the outer script are not loaded and ready for use yet. How can I do that and be sure that the script was fully loaded?

I've tried using `script.onreadystatechange` and `script.onload` callbacks but I'm having some browser compatibility issues.

How do I do that, as safely as possible, **with pure JS** and decent browser compatibility?

Sample:

**uno.js:**

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "dos.js";
script.type = "text/javascript";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
alert(outerVariable); // undefined
```

**dos.js:**

```
var outerVariable = 'Done!';
```

**sample.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="uno.js"></script>
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

Comment: Why not call a function from the script you load ? This way you would know it's loaded whatever the state change callback problems (that's what I do due to similar problems).

Comment: I'm not confident it's safe enough. But if I don't have a choice, I'll go with that.

Comment: What compatibility issues do you have?

Comment: It's not working properly on non-IE browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are concerned with non-IE browsers I would try using DOMContentLoaded to see if the script is fully loaded.

You can see more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

In fact this is sort of how JQuery works with document ready.  This is the snippit from the jquery source:

```
    if ( document.addEventListener ) {
                // Use the handy event callback
                document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", DOMContentLoaded, false );

                // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
                window.addEventListener( "load", jQuery.ready, false );
// If IE event model is used
        } else if ( document.attachEvent ) {
            // ensure firing before onload,
            // maybe late but safe also for iframes
            document.attachEvent( "onreadystatechange", DOMContentLoaded );

            // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
            window.attachEvent( "onload", jQuery.ready );

            // If IE and not a frame
            // continually check to see if the document is ready
            var toplevel = false;

            try {
                toplevel = window.frameElement == null;
            } catch(e) {}

            if ( document.documentElement.doScroll && toplevel ) {
                doScrollCheck();
            }
        }
```

If you were to look at the jquery code to copy what they do it's in the bind ready function of the full source code.

Comment: Ok, this seems nice, but it's intended for the `domReady` situation. How could it be adapted for the script loading situation? Just replace `document` for the `script` element?

Comment: Yes I would give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

So far, this seems to be the better working approach. Tested on IE9, Firefox and Chrome.

Any concerns?

**uno.js:**

```
function loadScript(url, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    if (navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == 'loaded') {
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        script.onload = function(){
            callback();
        };
    }
}

loadScript('dos.js', function(){
    alert(outerVariable); // "Done!"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use the  `onload` (IE9-11,Chrome,FF)  or `onreadystatechange`(IE6-9).

```
var oScript = document.getElementById("script")
        oScript.src = "dos.js"
        if (oScript.onload !== undefined) {
            oScript.onload = function() {
                alert('load')
            }
        } else if (oScript.onreadystatechange !== undefined) {
            oScript.onreadystatechange = function() {
                alert('load2')
            }
        }
```

Comment: Gives me compatibility issues, as described on the question.